# node.js xmlhttp get request getaddrinfor ENOTFOUND error

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, get, xmlhttprequest

Reaching out to see if anyone can let me know where I am going wrong with my code here. I am new to node.js and being behind a corporate proxy is making it tough for me to get going.

I am receiving the below error when trying to make a **xmlhttprequest** with **GET** method in node.js. I am using pure JavaScript without any frameworks as you can see from the code below.

```
Error:getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxx-api.xxx.com xxx-api.xxx.com :443
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInforReqWrap.onlookup [as incomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

[Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDtZX.png)

Since I am behind a proxy, I tried various methods to make '**npm install** xxxx' work. Finally, setting **"Automatically authenticate"** in 'rules' of **Fiddler** and changing npm config settings as below helped.

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888/
https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888/
http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
strict-ssl=false
```

After this, **npm install xmlhttprequest** worked fine for me. So I proceeded to execute my GET request as below:

```
function login()
{
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         var url = 'https://xxx-api.xxx.com/v1/login';
         var method='GET';
         var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if ("withCredentials" in xhr) 
         {
         xhr.open(method, url, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
       xhr.setRequestHeader('user', 'xxxx');
       xhr.setRequestHeader('password','xxxx');
     } 
     else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") 
     {
         xhr = new XDomainRequest();
       xhr.open(method, url);

     } 
     else 
     {
       xhr = null;
     }
     if (!xhr) 
     {
      console.log('CORS not supported');
     }
     xhr.onload = function() 
     {
       text = xhr.responseText;
       obj=JSON.parse(text);
       c=obj.certificate;

         if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {

              resolve(xhr.responseText);


       } 
       else {

        reject({
          status: xhr.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
       }
     };
     xhr.onerror = function() {
      console.log('There was an error making the request.');
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
         reject({
        status: xhr.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };

    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

You can see I am making a CORS API request here. However, this returns me the above error.

I used `nslookup xxx-api.xxx.com` and it returned me the server, address and Name perfectly fine. So I suspect this is not a dns or connection issue.

However, if I try the same code on my personal laptop outside the corporate network without changing any proxy settings,everything works as expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!